# Select query from related tables

Tags: mysql, go

I have tables:

Industry:

| industry_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | industry A |
| 2 | industry B |

Guide:

| industry_id | guide_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | guide A |
| 1 | 2 | guide B |
| 1 | 3 | guide C |
| 1 | 4 | guide D |
| 2 | 11 | guide E |

Previously I was referring to another table:

Summary:

| industry_id | guide_id | uuid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | AAAA |
| 1 | 2 | BBBB |
| 1 | 2 | CCCC |
| 1 | 3 | DDDD |
| 2 | 11 | EEEE |

I need to find items related to for industry_id 1 referred in summary table and get the data in this format:

| industry_id | guide_id | name | uuid | parent_uuid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | industry A | AAAA | null |
| 1 | 1 | guide A | BBBB | AAAA |
| 1 | 2 | guide B | CCCC | AAAA |
| 1 | 3 | guide C | DDDD | AAAA |

Query was, with some simplification:

```sql
select s.industry_id, 
i.guide_id, 
case s.guide_id null i.name ELSE g.name
s.uuid 
case s.guide_id null NULL ELSE (uuid of parent)
from summary s
left join industry i on s.industry_id=i.industry_id
left join guide g on s.industry_id=g.industry_id
Where s.industry_id =4
```

But now I cannot get data from summary table, instead need to use an API endpoint, which returns a response such as

```json
[ 
{
"industry_id": 1
"guide_id": null
"uuid": "AAAA"
},
{
"industry_id": 1
"guide_id": 1
"uuid": "BBBB"
},
{
"industry_id": 1
"guide_id": 2
"uuid": "CCCC"
},
{
"industry_id": 1
"guide_id": 3
"uuid": "DDDD"
}
]
```

I am writing Golang code.
So the way forward I am seeing

1. Make the API call and get the response.
2. Make list of Guide_id s in there
3. Get guide info via:

```sql
select * from guide where industry_id=4 and guide_id in (<The list created on step 2>)
```

4. Get industry info via:

```sql
select * from industry where industry_id=4
```

5. Add record from step 4 into records from step 3
6. Add UUID info got from API endpoint into records and return this result.

Is there an easier, cleaner way to do this?

Comment: You can try fetching both guide and industry info with a single query instead of querying twice.